# Are there any mods for writing notes on paper or books?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

Builders of adventure maps often use separate text files or maps (the item) to display the storyline. This seems a little silly since there are books in minecraft, but you can't write in them. Furthermore there are many items that might tie in with writing, such as paper and ink sacs.

Are there any mods that would help makers of adventure maps write their story in-game by making it possible to write in books?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of [Snapshot 12w17a](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history/Development_versions#Snapshot_12w17a), the [Book and Quill](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Book_and_Quill) has been added to the game, which allows users to write in books without the need to install any mods. The crafting recipe for the item is a Book, Feather, and Ink Sac anywhere in the crafting grid.

[image: Crafting recipe for Book and Quill]

[image: Screenshot of Book and Quill being used]

---

[Wurstknifte's Bookmod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/225057-10-wurstkniftes-bookmod-write-in-books/) seems to be a good fit. It adds a new kind of bookshelf that allows you to place coloured books inside of, and you can write (type) in the books. It's also compatible with 1.0.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There looks to be several mods of this sort around, such as [Tomes by PinkEmma](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/821714-100-pinkemmas-mods-xp-book-sspsmp-tomes-sspsmp-writable-books-new-update-8th-of-dec/):

[image]

Or, [this one here,](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/225057-10-wurstkniftes-bookmod-write-in-books/) Wurstknifte's Bookmod:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use a book and quill, you can write in them. You need a book, feather and inc sac, and you can put them anywhere on the crafting table. I hope this answers your question!

Comment: Hi Hanna, welcome to Arqade! It appears that the currently accepted answer already covers this info (complete with a picture of a crafting recipe). Is there any unique information that's not already in that answer that you'd like to add?

Answer (score -1):

Well, you have the tomes mod or wurstknife's books mod, but if you're patient enough, you could just wait for 1.3.